# geotools - creating a fan shape

Tags: java, drawing, shapes, geotools

I'm new to using geotools, and I would like to be able to draw fan shape - just the outline of the blue area.

[image: Fan shape example]

The parameters are:

1. Inner radius
2. Outer radius
3. Anchor position (centre)
4. Start sector angle
5. End sector angle

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/205751/79 help?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Ian!

I modified the algorithm in your [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/205751/79) to just create an arc (left to right) from a given radius, startAngle, sectorAngle to return an array of Coordinates.

I would create an arc with the outer radius, then create the 2nd arc with the inner radius. I would combine the 2 two arrays by adding the inner radius arc in reverse, then I would add the first point of outer radius arc to close the polygon.